# Почему не работает кастомная валидация Laravel Validator?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть кастомное правило для проверки даты. Все по документации Laravel, но при этом не срабатывает и всегда возвращает, что ошибок нет. dump и dd из метода passes не реагирует никак. Есть какие нибудь предположения?

```
class CheckDeliveryDate implements Rule
    {  
        public function passes($attribute, $value)
        {
            $delivery_date = Carbon::parse($value);

            if ($delivery_date->isToday()) {
                $this->error_messge = "Дата доставки не может быть сегодняшней";

                return false;
            }

            if ($delivery_date->endOfDay()->isPast()) {
                $this->error_messge = "Дата доставки не может быть прошедшей";

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public function message() {
            return $this->error_messge;
        }
    }
```

Подключаю в контроллере:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
    $this->rules($client_id)
);
```

Метод с массивом правил:

```
 public function rules($client_id) {
        return [
          'orders.*.positions.*.col' => 'required|numeric',
          'orders.*.positions.*.width' => 'required|numeric',
          'orders.*.positions.*.height' => 'required|numeric',
          'orders.*.positions.*.area' => 'nullable|numeric',
          'orders.*.positions.*.delivery_time' => ['required', 'date', new CheckDeliveryDate],
        ];
    }
```

Все остальные валидации работают корректно, но собственное отказывается работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел в чем проблема. Дело в том, что изначально формат данных, которые приходят отличался от первоначальной точки, соответственно структура JSON не соответствовала валидации.